# loopback component storage file upload request aborted formidable\lib\incoming_form.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, loopback, formidable

I have configured storage component of loopback successfully i.e. loopback-component-storage. I have been able to create folders. But when I try to upload files (using postman) it keeps giving request aborted error:

```
error:  Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\projects\TestProject\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:120:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:283:11)
    at TLSSocket.serverSocketCloseListener (_http_server.js:296:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at _handle.close (net.js:498:12)
    at Socket.done (_tls_wrap.js:325:7)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
```

I have also configured SSL, so the url is https://localhost/api/containers/container1/upload. Could this be an issue ? I am using the following modules in my package.json.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "helmet": "^3.4.1",
    "js2xmlparser": "^3.0.0",
    "loopback": "^3.4.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.23.0",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^4.1.1",
    "loopback-component-storage": "^3.2.0",
    "loopback-connector-rest": "^2.1.0",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^3.2.0",
    "loopback-ssl": "0.0.9",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "strong-error-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  }
```

The server.js file looks like below:

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
var loopbackSSL = require('loopback-ssl');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

var app = module.exports = loopback();
app.use(bodyParser.text());

app.start = function () {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function () {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (require.main === module)
    return loopbackSSL.startServer(app);
});
```

Could any of the above modules be an issue ? Looks like this is a node-formidable issue. Could anyone let me know ? Can we write a remote method to accept files ?

Comment: have you given permission to these folders that you have created?

Comment: yes permissions are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to fix this issue by removing

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```

from server.js. The files are getting uploaded now.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to comment for other viewers (but I don't have enough reputation), as I had a similar issue and removing the following worked for me:

`app.use(multer({storage: storage}).any())`

Thank you for posting this and the solution you found, my solution was almost identical.

Comment: I've just discovered this too. The problem is that I actually want to parse some multipart fields prior to the upload operation taking place. Have you by any chance worked out how multer can continue to be used with the storage component?

Comment: @Trevor I'm facing the same problem you had a few months ago and searched for a few hours already how to make this happen - did you find any solution?

Comment: @hajn Yes. With a bit of a facepalm, I eventually realised that the basic, fundamental problem in trying to enable multer is that you're trying to reuse a stream, which is impossible. You have multer trying to consume the stream, and then you have the multipart library that loopback-component-storage uses (can't recall which one) tryng to consume the stream, too. The only solution I found is that the text fields are provided in the `fields` property of the callback object from upload(). See my github ticket here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage/issues/233

Comment: However, I didn't use that solution, because the problem is that it delivers those fields to you AFTER the upload has taken place. I needed to have the text fields *before* the upload happened. The solution I went with in the end was to define a remote method / endpoint which requires the field(s) to be part of the request path/query string instead. Basically in my case all I needed to have along with the image was a client-supplied objectId, so my client puts that in the request path (/{id}) and so I'm able to grab that and use it to do my validation etc. *before* upload() happens.

Comment: So, in short, after many hours trying to solve this, the conclusion was basically: If you don't mind having the text fields passed to you *after* the upload, you can use the `fields` property passed back from upload(). However if you need to validate some fields before the upload takes place, the only way I could do it is to have those fields as part of the path. I've put up a gist for you of the relevant extract from my code: https://gist.github.com/TrevorPage/eeed5022e03978d9d003898ffe00f7db

Comment: @Trevor thank you for your extended explanation, that's exactly the problem I've been trying to wrap my head around. Since the validation should take place before the (possibly hundreds of MB large) file is uploaded, checking the fields after .upload() is not an option.
I wanted to achieve an endpoint, where files could either be uploaded via multipart/form-data and/or a path could be defined where data is located, to be downloaded before any other operation is done. This information would have been contained in the req.body, which is still empty before upload - unless I use multer middleware

Comment: when doing that, I could get the body populated, but I guess that's also only possible because an "upload" in memory has been done by the multer middleware? And because that stream is not possible to reuse, as I also found out after some more facepalming, that storage.upload can't process that request anymore .. I was wondering if there was any possibility to kind of "consume" the incoming stream two times, the first time to populate req.body via multer and the second time, after validation, to consume it via storage.upload?

Comment: However, even if it was possible to consume that request and file stream on the same endpoint twice, which I doubt, I think that would leave me with the same problem as before, namely having to upload a possibly large file to get the body (or the populated fields). I guess I have to adapt a solution similar to the gist you posted - thanks again for that. I am just wondering if it is such an edge case what we are trying to do or why there is no elegant solution to this problem..